# How to put a view on top of the status bar in React-Native for Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I need to put a view on top of the status bar and the status bar background should be white. How can i accomplish that in android using react native.

I have added the below lines in styles.xml but it is rendering a black statusbar and even tried it giving a transparent color.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I have also added the StatusBar tag from react-native and set it to hidden but this also is only giving a black statusbar and i am not able to put my view on top of the statusbar.

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
<StatusBar hidden> or <StatusBar hidden={true}>
```

The above code is also not working.

**--------EDIT-------**

**I solved the above problem by installing the [react-native-immersive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-immersive) package. It solved my issue with ease.**

Comment: Added the relevant steps tried for the solution.

Comment: I solved the above problem by installing the [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-immersive](react-native-immersive) package. It solved my issue with ease.